# What's this orange jelly on pomelo?

Tags: food-safety, fruit

I was peeling my pomelo when I noticed this orange gelatinous substance between slices. No other places were found and the fruit looks good from inside. Is it safe to eat?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is merely pectin, and completely safe!
Pectin can form naturally in fruit, and looks like jelly.